# Why wont this value work in a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

This is essentially what i'm doing

```
while(true)  //cant check for zero, there is more to do here
{
    int val = 0;

    for(SomeObject i : arrayListOfSomeObjects)
    {
        if(canDoSomething)
        {
            val++
        }
    }

    if(val == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        //do stuff with that nonzero value
    }
}
```

It is strange, because the loop wont yield. As in, stop if unsuccessful. I have a proceedure that will keep going until it finishes, if it does not do anything (or does not meet my conditions in that operation) it wont change the value. Meaning that check on "val" should break the loop. But it doesn't. It just going. I have even printed "val" to the console, yet it returns 0.

At the end of that operation, even if the value IS 0, it keeps going!

Comment: You tested with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned, the "val" is spitting out 0.

Comment: So does the above code halt or loop?

Comment: The above code halts perfectly fine, so I would assume that it's something outside of this loop. Try throwing a println inside the if statement and checking to make sure it is run. And a second println before the while loop to make sure it's not re-running the while loop after it's already broken out of it.

Comment: As an additional note, infinite loops are just asking for problems.

Comment: `//Some operation that will change the value IF successful ..`   if `val` is changing here with non zero value then it goes infinite.

Comment: It is working fine for me. There is some other problem.

Comment: Is this your real code? Or is in real life the value something other than an `int`? Perhaps the `if` is inside some other code? Also, why not use `do... while (val != 0);`? Endless loops have a higher chance of being... endless.

Comment: No this is not my real code, I updated it a bit more to explain why i cant put the != 0 condition IN the while loop, and yes inf's are problems, but sometimes, you cant go any other way

Comment: Once if `val` increased, then how it will become `if(val == 0)`, it will go for infinite loop only!!

Comment: it doesnt always increase. I will post the actual source, however, it WILL stop, there is a limit

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jq6Lnr9j     The actual source   As you can see, chg is the value that resets to 0 for every while iteration. If nothing happens, meaning the conditions arent met, the chg value will be 0, thus, breaking out

Comment: Not real code as there's a missing semi-colon, at least.  Why don't you post actual code which causes an actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.. Try the following..

```
int val = 1;
while(val>0)
{    

//Some operation that will change the value IF successful

}
```

Comment: Better use `val != 0`. `val` could also be changed to a negative value.

Comment: I updated my post to explain why i cant put the condition in the while

Comment: @DanielMills : define the val variable outside the while loop; if the loop is executed for the second time , new val object will created. ie there will be two val object. Due to that , i guess it not working..

Comment: if(chg == 0)
                        {
                             scanned =true;
                                break;
                        }

Answer (score 0):

first `int val = 0` supposed to be outside the loop because this will cause the value of the variable `val` always zero

Comment: Im not sure that is correct. INSIDE of the loop, the value has a chance of changing, if it does, it will continue. However at a point, it will break anyways.

Comment: This won't change, as value can be changed side the if statement, and if not then it should brean

Comment: You are right but have you tried a test case where it supposed to act as expected, I think the error coming from the "if (canDoSomething)" condition

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure you are targeting the 'right' loop by adding a label:

```
label: while(true)  //cant check for zero, there is more to do here
{
    // ...

    if(val == 0)
    {
        break label;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This will ensure that you break out of the `while` loop in case the check is in another loop or a `switch` statement. Otherwise, I am sure that something is causing the problem that you didn't show in your example. Beware of unwanted side-effects.